# Looping through an ArrayList and updating an attribute

Tags: java, jsp, session, arraylist

I'm trying to loop through an ArrayList in `start.jsp` and pass each item into a different jsp, `destination.jsp`. I am currently using sessions, and I am aware that the `session.setAttribute` function will overwrite whatever the previous values of the attribute were. Here is my code:

start.jsp:

```
// Main AL has the type ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>. I am trying to loop through the mainAL and pass each item in it to destination.jsp. 

...
// This snipet of code creates a button for each element in mainAL and submits the element to destination.jsp when clicked.
for (ArrayList<String> al : mainAL)
{
    <form action="destination.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <% session.setAttribute("list", al); %>
}
...
```

destination.jsp:

```
...
<% ArrayList<String> result = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("list"); %>
<%out.println(list);%>
...
```

If the `mainAL` has more than 1 item, every `destination.jsp` instance generated from the for loop will only show the last ArrayList from `mainAL`. How should I fix this problem? Is there any way to pass each ArrayList to `destination.jsp` without its value being overwritted?

Comment: This is the 21st century, do not put Java code into your JSP, use JSTL.  Also if you are `submitting` your form method should be a `POST`

Answer (score 1):

The session.setAttribute() function sets a value globally. It means, that you overwrite the value in every loop cycle. You will have to make hidden inputs, in witch you put your data, so it gets passed as a GET argument in the request url to your other destination site. At the destinations site you will have to retrieve that data from the request url. You can you use POST as well, when you want to keep your url clean. I would also recommended doing things like this with a session token instead of passing lists through inputs.

I hope that this helped you :)